# Does the green area converge to a known constant when $n\to \infty$?

Tags: integration, limits, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

[image: Euler Constant]

Let $n$ denote the number of the rectangles in the figure above.

We know that the gray area converges to 
[Euler-Mascheroni constant $(\gamma)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) when $n\to \infty$.

I have three questions about the green area:

$1)$ Does it converge to a known constant when $n\to \infty$?

$2)$ Can we relate it to $\gamma$ when $n\to \infty$?

$3)$ Which is one is larger when $n\to \infty$, the gray area or the green one?

I came come up with this question when I was searching about $\gamma$ and saw the image above and the green area brought my attention.

Thank you.

Comment: The total area of the rectangles under the green converges to the area under the curve, so wouldn't the area of the green have to converge to $0$ because there isn't any room left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your picture, we have:
$$
\text{gray}+\text{green} = \lim_{n\to{\infty}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j+1}\right)}
$$
This telescopes, showing
$$
\text{gray}+\text{green} = 1
$$
Therefore
$$
\text{green} = 1-\text{gray} = 1-\gamma
$$
Because the graph $1/x$ is convex, we have $\text{green} < \text{gray}$.  In fact, $\gamma \approx 0.57$ so $1-\gamma \approx 0.43$.

Comment: Very nice  and simple (+1). Thanks